# Always start Oracle DB in Idle State

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2

Is there a way to setup your Oracle db to always be brought up in an idle state so that you can then 'startup' when you want to use it. I'm running Oracle 11g R2 on Windows with lean resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Starting and Stopping the Database with Oracle Administration Assistant for Windows](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/install.112/e47798/startrdb.htm#NTDBI2841)

> To start or stop the database:
>
> From the Start menu, select All Programs, then Oracle - HOME_NAME,
>   then Configuration and Migration Tools, and then Administrative
>   Assistant for Windows.
>
> In the console window, expand the Oracle Administration Assistant for
>   Windows tree structure.
>
> Under Databases, right-click the name of the database, and from the
>   menu, select from the following options:
>
> Connect Database
>
> Start Service
>
> Disconnect Database
>
> Stop Service
>
> Startup/Shutdown Options
>
> Process Information

At Startup/Shutdown Options, you can set whether the instance should start when the Windows service belonging to that database instance starts.

[image]

Another method is to use the command line, disabling the automatic startup of the instance of database ORCL:

`oradim -edit -sid ORCL -STARTMODE manual`